# How to integrate Angular 6 app with Drupal 7 as a custom module?

Tags: angular, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am trying to integrate angular 6 application with drupal version 7 but not able to find a solution to integrate the app with drupal version 7. Can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 0):

The question needs to be refined. Is your app the front-end to the Drupal site ? If  so you can put the contents of your dist folder in the web root, starting with index.html; or host it somewhere else altogether (main domain of the site with the Drupal site hosted on a subdomain). Is your  app using Drupal 7 as an API back-end ? Then use JSON Views to obtain the data and Services endpoints to create, update or delete nodes.